# unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, mysql

I uploaded a php file to my server and I got this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /www/zzl.org/m/a/d/madebytheo/htdocs/cms/index.php on line 3

Here is line three:

```
mysql_connect (localhost, password, username) or die (mysql_error());
```

Any idea what's wrong?

**EDIT**
It turned out to be the lack of quotes.

Comment: Are `localhost`, `password` and `username` variables? are they strings?

Comment: How are we to know, without any context? You need to show us the preceding lines, also. Ideally, narrow your problem down to a couple of lines of code that constitute a full program, and show us that. (More than likely, you will find the problem on your own by doing this; this is known as _debugging_.)

Comment: they aren't constants but rather I just substituted the words password and username for the actual password and usernanme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ussually that kind of error is because some trivial typo. In this case, if the above code is your actual code, then you should use double quote to wrap `localhost`, `password` and `username`.

Comment: Actually, he should use single quotes.  Unless they are variables (in which, he is then missing $ signs), there is no reason to have double quotes - its just inefficient.

Comment: @Chris: It will make hardly a blind bit of difference. Quit trying to micro-optimise.

Comment: I agree that it won't make a difference here, but why teach poor programming practices?  If codedude goes on to make a huge application that deals with strings (or works for a company that relies heavily on efficient and speedy execution), it could have a very large effect (from experience).

Comment: i'll try the single quotes and see if the error disappears

Comment: For anyone which works for years in large project with a group of developer teams, hear someone which try to related trivial stuff like double quotes/single quotes with high performance application is really...funny.

Comment: @Chris, If you give yourself more time, to understand what I said, before hastily responded in part that may makes you feel offended, then you will realize that there is no single thing about your statement, which I rejected, of your the most utter, most ultimate and comment-of-the-century-super-duper conclusion that emerged from you about the Single Quoted vs Double Quoted. Referencing your link, just prove what i said : `Concatenation vs. interpolation is meaningless (in real world performance) if your database queries are poorly written or you aren't using any kind of caching scheme`.

Answer (score 0):

Dollar signs(?) are missing.

```
mysql_connect($localhost, $password, $username) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: This would not yield a parse error; it would lead PHP to assume that the constants are supposed to be strings, and throw a notice.

Comment: @Tomalak True, but that was my best guess.  :P

Comment: OP doesn't seem terribly bothered about coming back and providing the details we need to help him with this question.

Comment: the values arent' variables but rather words subsituted for the actual password and username just to preserve security.